# packer command got stuckl

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, packer

Packer command got stuck with no output. On doing strace I got below output. Can you please share your inputs on it? I tried to run with debug commands .`packer  build -debug` . However it does not print output.

````
                            = 0
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f44aad8b000
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7f44aad8b740) = 0
mprotect(0x7f44aa748000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f44aa967000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f44aab72000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x601000, 4096, PROT_READ)     = 0
mprotect(0x7f44aad95000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7f44aad8e000, 20954)           = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x6a5000
brk(0x6c6000)                           = 0x6c6000
brk(NULL)                               = 0x6c6000
open("build.pwd", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = 3
open("build.pwi", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = 4
open("build.hwm", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = 5
fstat(4, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f44aad93000
fstat(0, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(136, 0), ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f44aad92000
read(0, ^Cstrace: Process 3301 detached
 <detached ...>
[root@h2o-instance-workspace packer]# ^C ```
````

Comment: Try environment variable `PACKER_LOG=1` before execution.

Answer (score 0):

As per your post if you're using **packer   build -debug** command, kindly remove the extra space and i.e looks like **packer build -debug**. you can also assign an environment variable before execution.

You can set the detailed logs environmental variable PACKER_LOG or the log variable PACKER_LOG_PATH using powershell [environment variables](https://www.packer.io/docs/debugging).

For example:
$env:PACKER_LOG=1
$env:PACKER_LOG_PATH="packerlog.txt"